# How can I check the difference between a Postman request and a Python http request?

Tags: python, http, postman, aiohttp

I've been pulling my hair out the past couple of days trying to get a Python http request to work. I can get it working using Postman, but for some reason it just won't work no matter what I do in Python. I'm hoping if I can compare some raw version of the two requests I can see what the differences might be.

For Postman, I'm simply POSTing like this:

[image]

The header is an authentication token, identical to the one I'm using in Python. Here's my python code:

```
text = open(filepath, 'rb').read()
body = aiohttp.formdata.FormData()
body.add_field('files', text, filename=f'{filepath}')
resp = await session.post(url=self.ip_address + '/upload',
                          headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.jwt}'},
                          data={'files': body})
resp.raise_for_status()
html = await resp.text()
return html
```

But I get a 500 response:

> [2019-09-05T18:50:04.751Z] error TypeError: Cannot destructure
>   property `refId` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
>       at upload (/home/ubuntu/project.strapi/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/controllers/Upload.js:26:66)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by changing the parameter in post() to just `data=body`